# Is better to use only media queries for the mobile devices and desktops or media queries without any definition?

Tags: css, performance

For better performance, is it better to have this:

```
#A {
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
#A{ 
  margin: 10px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
 #A {
  margin: 200px;
 }
}
```

or this:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
#A{ 
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
 #A {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 200px;
 }
}
```

I would like to understand if it is better to also have "generic" `CSS` (not inside a media query) than to have only CSS inside media query depending to the screen size.

Sorry for my English (and title)... thanks a lot! :)

Comment: My first concern would be: what makes the shortest, most maintainable CSS. Performance will rarely be a concern. Clearly in this case, the first example wins. If you want to change the background colour and border radius, in the first example you need to change 2 lines and in the second you need to change 4.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first option would be better. You are only changing the property that changes across media-queries, rather than resetting all the properties.

Duplication of styles is a code smell and can lead to unmaintainable css at larger scales.

You could optimise even further and set one of the margins as a default, only then overriding when the breakpoint is hit.

```
 #A {
   background: #000;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
   #A {
    margin: 200px;
   }
  }
```

Comment: This style is also significantly easier to port to a CSS preprocessor later on.